# MariaDB ODBC connector connects to all databases indiscriminately

Tags: mariadb, odbc, windows-10

This is connector 3.3.4 (64-bit). OS is W10. 
`mariadb --version` gives
"mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.7.3-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64), source revision ..."

I wanted to set up an ODBC connector primarily to construct a front end using LibreOffice Base. I've been using this for some time, using a 32/64-bit MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode connector. But seeing as I'm using MariaDB as my database system, it seemed sensible to use the latest and best MariaDB connector.

On the second dialog of the ODBC data source setup, "Create a new Data Source to MariaDB" you are asked to choose your database. So I chose one of the databases on my system.

I've since found, however, on opening an .odb (LO Base file) and using this ODBC connection, that ALL the tables in ALL the databases in my MariaDB system are listed under "Tables". This is not the case with the above MySQL connector: it shows only the tables for the specified database.

Is there a way to configure this to restrict to the one database? It seems to be an anomaly: why would you be asked to "Please specify a database to use" if all the databases, not just the one chosen, are then going to be exposed in that connection?